# VS 2010 post build, show application console

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, post-build-event

I have set post build command line, that will run a console application(C#). VS runs the application as it should but I want to see that console application window. Looks like VS create process with no window, so I tried to use

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
```

but it doesnt work too.

**Edit**: (Added command line)

> "C:\AfterBuild.exe" "arg" "$(TargetDir)"

Comment: Can you add the text of your post build event?

Comment: Added command line of post build

Comment: try using `bat` file to run your command.

Comment: bat file doesn't work either

Comment: Did you try to use the 'Start' command ? (http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

Comment: Yes `START` command worked. Would be nice if you write it as answer. Thank you Yaniv.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the 'Start' command in order to launch a new console and run your commands.

For example, create a batch file like this, save it as test.bat:

```
@echo This is a test.
```

Now run start with this file as a parameter:

```
start test.bat
```

The batch file will run on a new console window.

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 1):

In case someone wants the command window to be left open after the build process runs:

```
cd "$(SolutionDir)MYPROJECTNAME\$(OutDir)\$(ConfigurationName)"
```

start cmd /k MYPROJECTNAME.exe